# FW1 - 404 error instead of processing controller

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, fw1

I started this job recently. The site is written in CF using the FW1 framework (I'm brand new to FW1). I am building out a 2012 R2 server and upgrading to CF11 at the same time. I copied the site files over and the home page loads correctly so I know the framework is basically functioning. However, when I click to another section (www.site.com/about) I get a 404 error instead of the framework processing the section. Any thoughts? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Not much to go on; I'm going to guess the friendly URLs are not being routed to the correct controller